# Use imports inside interface definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I'm having a strange problem with typescript interfaces. Because I'm using mongoose models I need to define one, but for some reason it's not recognising things that I have explicitly imported. This part works fine:

```
export interface ITrip extends mongoose.Document {
    //
}

export var TripSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    //
});

export var Trip = mongoose.model<ITrip>('Trip', TripSchema);
```

Now, I'm defining another interface, that has an array of Trip. I need this for [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

```
import {Trip, ITrip} from '../trips/trip.model';

export interface IFeed extends mongoose.Document {
  lastSnapshot: {
    trips: [Trip]
  }
}
```

The TS compiler gives this error: `feed.ts(12,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Trip'.` (referring to `trips: [Trip]`). It doesn't say that the import failed or anything. I can even use trip inside the same file to create new objects `var a = new Trip({});` without problem. Inside the interface it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trip` isn't a type, it's a variable, so you can do this:

```
let t = Trip;
let t2 = new Trip({});
```

But you can't do this:

```
let t: Trip;
```

You should change it to `typeof Trip`:

```
export interface IFeed extends mongoose.Document {
    lastSnapshot: {
        trips: [typeof Trip]
    }
}
```

Also, if you want `IFeed.lastSnapshot.trips` to be an array, then it should be:

```
trips: typeof Trip[]
```

What you declared is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of one item.

---

#### Edit

With an object the assignment is always the same (both js and ts):

```
let o = {
    key: "value"
}
```

But when declaring types in typescript then you're not dealing with values:

```
interface A {
    key: string;
}

let o: A = {
    key: "value"
}
```

In the mongoose documentation they are using only javascript so all of their examples don't include the type declarations.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: isn't all JS syntax supposed to work in TS as well? I figured the syntax on the mongoose website would work.

Comment: What syntax? Please be more specific

Comment: On the mongoose documentation page they write `children: [childSchema]`. How come it works in plain javascript?

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Hey, last question: If I do `feed.lastSnapshot.trips.push(trip);`, what type should trip be? I'm assuming it should be `ITrip` but in that case I'm getting the error `can't convert ITrip to Model<ITrip>`. Obviously new mongoose Trip-object I create are `ITrip`. Any idea?

Comment: I haven't used mongoose, but it seems fair to say that if `Trip = mongoose.model<ITrip>` then `typeof Trip` is `Model<ITrip>`, and so your trips array is `Model<ITrip>[]`.

Comment: You're right, my trips type should have been `ITrips`. Thanks again